# Oracle SQL - repeating same column value within a group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'd like some help tweaking the following query

```
select 
    data.smalldate, 
    mip.mip_step_description, 
    error_code.error_code_en, 
    count(case when (error_code is null and quality_plan is null) then data.part_serial_number end) as "Input", 
    count(case when error_code is not null then data.part_serial_number end) as "Defects"
from Data

left join MIP
On data.equipment = mip.equipment

left join error_code
on data.error_code = error_code.error_code_sn 

group by data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, error_code.error_code_en

order by data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, count(data.part_serial_number) desc
```

As you can see in the select statement, I'm using case statements within my count functions. This works fine. Data output looks like this

```
Date    MIP_Desc    Error_Code    Input    Defects
1/1/2011    MIP Z    (null)       100      0
1/1/2011    MIP Z    A            0        10
1/1/2011    MIP Z    B            0        15
```

I'd like to fill in the same input value in the input column throughout all the rows that have the same date and MIP_Desc.

Output should look like this

```
Date    MIP_Desc    Error_Code    Input    Defects
1/1/2011    MIP Z    (null)       100      0
1/1/2011    MIP Z    A            100      10
1/1/2011    MIP Z    B            100      15
```

Comment: gotta do two group bys (that is use a sub-query) -- join to the smaller one to get the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help? (untested):

```
SELECT smalldate, mip_step_description
     , error_code_en
     , MAX("Input") OVER (PARTITION BY smalldate, mip_step_description) "Input"
     , "Defects"
  FROM (select data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, error_code.error_code_en
             , count(case when (error_code is null and quality_plan is null)
                          then data.part_serial_number end) as "Input"
             , count(case when error_code is not null 
                          then data.part_serial_number end) as "Defects"
             , count(data.part_serial_number) sn_ct
          from DATA left join MIP On data.equipment = mip.equipment
                    left join ERROR_CODE on data.error_code = error_code.error_code_sn 
         group by data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, error_code.error_code_en)
order by smalldate, mip_step_description, sn_ct desc;
```

Comment: This worked great!
If I replace smalldate with to_char(data.scan_time, 'mmdd') I get errors saying it doesn't invalid identifier on data.scan_time, any ideas on this??

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. It seems that in the sub-query, when you  select .... As "Name", then "Name" is case sensitive in the main query.

I'm loving this partition feature!

Comment: Yes, double quotes in Oracle specify an identifier that is case-sensitive. I generally try to stay away from mixed-case identifiers because of the confusion that can be generated.